# Either[A, Future[B]] to Future[Either[A, B]]

Tags: scala, future

Is there a way to convert a

```
Either[A, Future[B]]
```

to a

```
Future[Either[A, B]]
```

I have in mind something like the `Future.sequence` method which converts from a `List[Future]` to a `Future[List]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure there's an out of the box solution, this is what I came up with:

```
def foldEitherOfFuture[A, B](e: Either[A, Future[B]]): Future[Either[A, B]] =
  e match {
    case Left(s) => Future.successful(Left(s))
    case Right(f) => f.map(Right(_))
  }
```

In addition to catch eventual exception from the `Future` you can add a `recover` and map it to a `Left`:

```
case Right(f) => f.map(Right(_)).recover { case _ => Left(/** some error*/) }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no api functional call to do that. I'd try something like this:

```
def getResult[A, B]: Either[A, Future[B]] = ???
val res = getResult.fold(fa = l => Future(Left(l)), fb = r => r.map(value => Right(value)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using scalaz, you can just use `sequenceU`

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val x: Either[String, Future[Int]] = ???
val y: Future[Either[String, Int]] = x.sequenceU
```

Update (August 2019):

If you're using cats, use `sequence`:

```
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val x: Either[String, Future[Int]] = ???
val y: Future[Either[String, Int]] = x.sequence
```

Comment: I think it's helpful to look at Haskell's `sequence` type signature (at least it helps me to figure out which higher order function would work in my Scala code): `sequence :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`.

Comment: I really hope this gets added to Scala core in 2.14 

Answer (score 1):

[Dumonad](https://github.com/dumonad/dumonad#dumonad) adds a set of extension methods to ease of reactive programming:

```scala
import io.github.dumonad.dumonad.Implicits._

val eitherOfFuture: Either[L,Future[R]]

val futureOfEither: Future[Either[L,R]] = eitherOfFuture.extractFuture
```